# d3 send mouse event to divs child element

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, children, preserve

Trying to drag/drop a complete form contained in a div,
the problem is to preserve the default behavior
of the child elements (here the text-input to 
allow e.g. text-selection by mouse) and  to restrain the 
dragstart to the div#dragme border part.

A description is here 
  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#on
how to preserve some undesired behavior while dragging elements,
but I guess here the opposite wold be desirable here, 
which means (something like) send the event to the divs
childs and cause them to perform their default behaviors.

Here is the code, please try to select the text via mouse 
(or select whole text via doubleclick), it wont' work:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
        div#dragme { 
                position:  absolute;
                overflow: hidden;
                left: 20;
                top: 20; 
                width: auto;
                background: silver; 
                border: 15px  solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
                border-radius: 4px; padding: 8px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <script src="d3.js"></script>

    <div id="container"  onclick="mouseclick(event)" > 
    </div>

    <script>
        elem = document.createElement("div");
        elem.id = 'content';
        elem.innerHTML = '<div draggable="true" id="dragme" class="resizeable"><input type="text" value="my text" />    </div>';
        document.body.insertBefore(elem,document.body.childNodes[0]);

        function move(){
            console.log("target: "+  d3.event.target);
            var dragTarget = d3.select(this);
            dragTarget
            .style("left", function(){return d3.event.dx + parseInt(dragTarget.style("left"))})
            .style("top", function(){return d3.event.dy + parseInt(dragTarget.style("top"))});
        }; 

        var node_drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                      .on("drag", move);
        var nodes =  d3.selectAll("#dragme");
        nodes.call(node_drag);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could suppress the drag on that element:

```
function move() {
  // if dragging on an input
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent.target.nodeName === "INPUT")
    return false;
  var dragTarget = d3.select(this);
  dragTarget
    .style("left", function() {
      return d3.event.dx + parseInt(dragTarget.style("left"))
    })
    .style("top", function() {
      return d3.event.dy + parseInt(dragTarget.style("top"))
    });
};
```

**EDITS**

Above didn't work in IE, So...

Back to original move function:

```
function move() {
  var dragTarget = d3.select(this);
  dragTarget
    .style("left", function() {
      return d3.event.dx + parseInt(dragTarget.style("left"))
    })
    .style("top", function() {
      return d3.event.dy + parseInt(dragTarget.style("top"))
    });
};
```

And suppress move events on input box:

```
var node_drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("drag", move);
var nodes = d3.selectAll("#dragme");
nodes.call(node_drag);

d3.select("#dragme > input").on("mousedown", function(){
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RdZtkaTIAOB6SW7d7X9G?p=preview).

Comment: The text in the example still is not selectable.

Comment: @Mike75, ughh damn IE, works in Chrome though, let me take another look.

Comment: Still strange: when I copy the lines:
    d3.select("#dragme > input").on("mousedown", function(){
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
  });

into my original move procedure it still has no effect !??
I use firefox with ubuntu 14.
This:
    d3.select("#dragme > input").on("mousedown", function(){
      d3.event.stopPropagation();
      alert("here I am");
    });
shows the message but not text selection. I don't understand that.

Comment: @Mike75, you copied that into the move function?  It belongs outside of it after the `nodes.call(node_drag)`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem recently by adding a mouseover/mouseout handler on a textarea to turn the parent div's drag behavior off and on, e.g.:

```
        var e = elem.find('textarea');
        e.on('mouseover', function(){ elem.draggable('destroy') });
        e.on('mouseout', function(){ elem.draggable() });
```

Comment: Where should this be placed?
I putted it after 
  nodes.call(node_drag);
and there it did not change the behavior (input still not selectable)
Also I tried with find('input') instead of find('textarea').